# How to convert an age interval into a decimal year number in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I try to convert an interval like "29 years 6 mons 22 days 21:17:52.860842" into a decimal year reprensentation like 29,55 years in PostgreSQL.

Comment: how would you define the length of a year exactly?

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I could take the days and divide them through 365, but this does not include leap years. Is there some build in function for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '29 years 6 mons 22 days 21:17:52.860842')/31557600;
```

where 31557600 is roughly the number of seconds in a year.

Comment: You might want to `ROUND` that - I'm not sure anybody's interested in people's age to the nanosecond! :-)

Comment: From [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year), that should be 31556952 seconds!   :-)

Comment: But I second the value that @Verace mentions here. Why use an approximate number when we know exactly how many seconds are in a year!

Comment: There are leap days and leap seconds on some years. So you can't know how many seconds there are in "one year". You can only have an approximation or you can calculate each year (in history) separately. Leap seconds are usually known only about six months in advance. I gave one approximation, you can pick another. And on `ROUND`, a decimal value was asked, and given :)